# If $Y$ is path connected, the set $[X,Y]$ has a single element proof critique

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let me provide some context behind this question. This comes from Munkers section 51 question 2b where he asks us to prove that if $Y$ is a path connected topological space and $I = [0,1]$ the set $[I, Y]$ has a single element where $[I, Y]$ represents the set of homotopy classes of maps of $I$ into $Y$.

I wrote a proof for this question but then realized that my proof did not rely on $I$ at all and could be generally applied to show this statement to be true for any $[X, Y]$ where $Y$ is path connected. This is clearly a much stronger statement, so I highly doubt its validity. However, I am having difficulty seeing exactly where my proof fails. So, any help in showing me the error in my proof would be appreciated. My proof is as follows:

Let $\phi$, $\tilde{\phi}$ be any 2 paths from $X \rightarrow Y$. Since Y is path connected, $\exists$ a path $\psi$ from $\phi(x)$ to $\tilde{\phi}(x)$  $\forall x \in X$.
So, define $\Phi(x,t): X \times X \rightarrow Y$ by $\Phi(x,t) = t\psi(\phi(x)) + (1-t)(\phi(x))$. When $t = 0$, we get $\phi(x)$ and when $t = 1$, we get $\psi(\phi(x)) = \tilde{\phi}(x)$ Since $\Phi$ consists of addition, multiplication, and composition of continuous functions, it too must be continuous. Therefore, $\phi$ and $\tilde{\phi}$ must be homotopic. QED

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: First, what does "$+$" mean in $Y$? Second, you're describing a "straight-line homotopy" from $\psi \phi$ to $\tilde{\phi}$. What if $Y$ has holes? Why is $\Phi(x,t) \in Y$ for all $x$ and $t$?

Comment: Third, $\psi$ should not be a function of $\phi(x)$ but of $x$ and some parameter $s\in[0,1].$ And since you choise it independently for each $x\in X,$ in has no reason to be continuous w.r.t. $x.$ For all these reasons, I think you should first present your proof in the case $X=I.$

Answer (score 4):

Remark: this is extremely false if you consider *based* homotopy classes instead (let $Y$ be the unit circle).

Hints:

1. Any path can be "shrunk".
2. What does it mean for two constant maps (points) to be homotopic?

And as commented, a generic $Y$ has no notion of $+$ or 'straight-line', etc. - be sure to avoid thinking purely in terms of $\Bbb R^n$ when doing topology

Answer (score 2):

As already remarked by other people, straight-line homotopies do not make sense for spaces without a vector space (or sufficiently linear) structure.

A general statement one can prove is that for **contractible** $X$ and pathconnected $Y$ the set $\[X,Y\]$ is the singleton. The categorical way to see this is to use the fact that the given homotopy equivalence $X \simeq *$ induces an isomorphism in the homotopy category $\mathsf{hoTop}$, hence a bijection of its hom-sets $\[X,Y\]\cong\[*,Y\]$. But the latter set is by definition the set of path-components of $Y$, which is the singleton, since $Y$ is assumed to be path-connected.